# Which version of the UGC docs are correct?

Tags: linkedin-api

I avoided using the UGC API on my recent migration to v2 of the LinkedIn API because this page of the docs (dated 2/4/2019, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api) suggests that the UGC is an "upcoming" API, only available for uploading videos, but not retrieving them (e.g. "UGC Post is currently best suited for creating and fetching video posts" and "Use the UGC Post API to create video content for organic posts and video ads. More functionality will be soon be added to the UGC Post API. As of now, you cannot retrieve the actual video content of a video post. This feature will be available soon.").

However, I just found this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/marketing/context#creating-a-share-on-linkedin) page, which talks about Sharing on LinkedIn, and seems to suggest using the UGC endpoint to upload text posts, article shares, and images.

Does anyone have a clear picture of what it is ready and not ready to go? I don't want to build out our app to use endpoints that are available only for testing, etc. I would like to know that LinkedIn officially supports the APIs that I am using in my app. I know LinkedIn monitors SO and touts it as part of their official mechanism for support, so I am posting this here.

At any rate, it might be a good idea to bring these two pages into alignment to prevent confusion like this.

===

EDIT: Noticed today that the link to the UGC docs is now time-stamped 4/10/2019. Not immediately clear to me what the changes between 2/4 and 4/10 are.

Answer (score 1):

We use LinkedIn V2 UGC API to post articles, images etc. and it works fine. However, uploading video results in an error that we do not have permission. I am not sure if there is any special permission that is needed even when we can post images fine.

Answer (score 1):

We use UGC API (V2).Here is documentation for reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/marketing/context#creating-a-share-on-linkedin

Video upload end point is not yet released. if you access that it will return  permission required response.

Comment: Interesting and good to know. On that link, it says `Similar to the author parameter we've used with the ugcPosts API, we will need to provide our Person URN.` Do you know if you can also pass an Organization URN here or does it have to be a Person URN?

Comment: Person URN needed  to post to the  personal profile. To manage company pages  We should apply for the API acess